# How to structure a web-facing server with high bandwidth requirements?

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, apache2

I am designing a service for a web-based scientific computing platform which involves uploading large data files (many GBs). Each file also contains cookies in the header that allows my server to authenticate the user. Multiple users may be uploading these files at once.

It is imperative that these files be encrypted with SSL, and it would be nice (but not absolutely necessary) to send all requests to our primary web-facing domain name which has an Apache server handling all requests. Our servers are hosted on Google Compute engine. I have multiple back-end servers for actually processing the data files, and currently the data requests are being proxied using `mod_proxy` to the back-end servers.

However, even with the proxy all the data still flows through the web-facing server before being sent to the back-end servers. This can easily bog down the web-facing server and my website.

My question is: how is this scenario usually dealt with? (sorry, I'm not an IT guy, but have to implement this myself)

Is a redirect used instead of a proxy in these scenarios? I've tried redirects, but the original header information is lost, and the back-end servers cannot retrieve the authentication cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a load balancer. There are heavy weight softwares to do this but you can create a simple load balancer with Apache using mod_proxy_balancer. And it can keep track of sessions so the header information should not get lost.